# Reading from an SQS queue with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

**Note**: this is a repost of a thread from [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236599&tstart=0).

Hi all,
I've got a process that processes messages in a single SQS queue. The queue can have many message in it and each message results in a database hit. Therefore I wanted to thread the readers of this queue.

The basic code for each thread is:

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        ReceiveMessageRequest rmr = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl)
               .withMaxNumberOfMessages(10)
               .withWaitTimeSeconds(3);
        List<Message> messages = sqsClient.receiveMessage(rmr).getMessages();
        // process messages
        // delete messages
    }
}
```

What I'm seeing is that there are tons of duplicated messages between the threads. I know that I should expect a few duplicates here and there but it appears that each thread gets the same set of messages and, realistically, only one thread ever does much work.

Am I misunderstanding how to use the API or am I doing something else wrong? The Javadocs indicate that the AmazonSQS class is threadsafe and, indeed, even creating a new AmazonSQS class for each thread changed nothing.

Any pointers would be most appreciated. My current thought of a fix is to have a single thread reading from the SQS queue, putting each message into something like a LinkedBlockingDeque and then have the workers reading that. But I feel that that implementation will not drain the queue as fast as I'd like.

Comment: What about listening to the queue in a single thread, and then spinning up new threads to process each message you receive?

Comment: @Mark B - That's a variation of what I proposed in my last paragraph - I was hoping to avoid that but it may be the best bet.

Comment: How long does your process take? You may need to use setVisibilityTimeout on your message request to give your process time to process and delete the messages.

Comment: @stdunbar: Though late, but it depends on how fast you want to write to db(say S tps) and difference between speed of SQS fetch(spSqs) and db write(spDB). If you can poll X messages in one call, then go for single thread, if S > (X*spSQS)/spDB, else opt for multithread, assuming one write db call per message. Next, about receiving duplicate messages, you can fetch from multiple threads and put it all in a single hashset(duplicates will be removed), and then write all in DB.

Comment: @stdunbar: One question: is sqs supposed to return duplicates?

Comment: @stdunbar did you figure it out eventually? I'm running into the same problem. An Akka actor is processing Akka messages to retrieve SQS messages.  Since each Akka message can be processed in a context of a different thread, there are a lot of duplicated messages as of result of reading them from multiple threads. I'm leaning towards pinning the actor to a single thread but it would be interesting to know whether it works with multiple threads in principle

Comment: @saurabheights Yes, SQS will return a message until the message is deleted. The message is not returned if it is inflight (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html).

Comment: @DenisMakarenko It should work with multiples threads, just mind the visibility timeout (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html).

Answer (score 5):

As you have a database hit for each message, it seems that processing each message takes time. You should increase the visibility timeout of the queue.

From AWS SQS documentation:

> Immediately after the message is received, it remains in the queue. To
>   prevent other consumers from processing the message again, Amazon SQS
>   sets a visibility timeout, a period of time during which Amazon SQS
>   prevents other consuming components from receiving and processing the
>   message.

(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html)

Comment: Low visibility timeout could cause issues with duplicate messages in the case of long message processing time but it clearly wasn’t the root cause in my case as it was set to 3 minutes and I saw duplicated messages well before SQS would make them available again. I ended up using pinned dispatcher in Akka to guarantee that a single thread does all the reading from the queue. Message processing though is done by different threads to prevent it interfering with reading new messages from the queue

Answer (score -1):

This will ensure duplicate message, you can skip duplicate message using this code

```
 var receivedCounts = message.Attributes.Where(x => x.Key == "ApproximateReceiveCount").FirstOrDefault();
                            if (message.Attributes != null && message.Attributes.Count > 0 &&
                                message.Attributes.Any(x => x.Key == "ApproximateReceiveCount") && receivedCounts.Value != "1")
                            {
                                AppLogger.LogError("Duplicate message arrived");
                                listDeleteMessageBatchRequestEntry.Add(new DeleteMessageBatchRequestEntry()
                                {
                                    Id = message.MessageId,
                                    ReceiptHandle = message.ReceiptHandle
                                });
                                continue;
                            }
```

Comment: This solution also throws away messages that may be valid, but failed to be handled be a consumer. I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: To say nothing of the fact that attempted re-delivery after the visibility window expires is a crucial *feature* of SQS in ensuring that each message is eventually processed even in the face of systems that may crash or fail on a message. That reliability is a big part of the reason to perform queueing in the first place. Don't delete messages with a receive count > 1.